# Change matplotlib figure rendering back to default in jupyter notebook

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I ran `%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'retina'` in a jupyter notebook to change the way the notebook renders matplotlib figures.

How do I reverse that **without restarting the kernel**?

I'm asking because some figures look better with `%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'retina'` and some look better with the default settings. Just curious how can you switch between the two across the notebook.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
from matplotlib_inline.backend_inline import set_matplotlib_formats
set_matplotlib_formats('svg')
```

I found you can set the format to:

- `'png'`
- `'retina'`
- `'jpeg'`
- `'svg'`
- `'pdf`

Where each has some pros and cons.